# delete from database after browser close

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am developing an E-Commerce application. But the problem is when user adds a product to cart and close the browser before order, the cart takes all the products. All the cart items are saved in a table.

I just want to flush the cart if the user closes the browser without ordering.

Comment: save the contents of the cart or at least the products ids to cookie then only process the cookie when order is submitted

Comment: yes I am using sessions. But once the user add a product to database, the product saves in a cart table.

Comment: You could try some experimenting with `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` events and callbacks, but this is not very reliable. Better would be to purge all carts older than 24 hours by cronjob.

Comment: what happens if the user's computer loses power or network connection, and you never get to know when they've closed the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript event to catch browser close and sent ajax request to some script that will delete cart data:

**UPDATED**

```
<script language="javascript">
function fnUnloadHandler() {
  xmlhttp=null; 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
     {// code for Firefox, Opera, IE7, etc. 
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
     } 
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
     {// code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
     } 

  if (xmlhttp!=null) 
     {  
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://yourhost/del_cart_actionFile.php",true); 
        xmlhttp.send(null); 
     } 
     else 
     { 
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP."); 
     } 
}
</script>
<body onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()">
</body>
```

Comment: what happens if the user's browser or computer crashes?

Comment: Nothing heppens, user data will be still in database. the solution is add to each item in cart table the timestamp data and check (using cron) the date differense in it. if difference > 1 day then delete this data.

Comment: I am a newbie in AJAX. Please can you describe what will be the code for deletion in AJAX.

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy thanks for the help but I stuck with the same code, Its working in all browser but in IE it will execute after every page refresh, whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of **reliably** knowing/alerting the server when a user closes his browser. You need to rethink your design: i.e do not persist cart items to the database unless checkout is completed. You can and should keep cart items in the user session, or possibly in cookies client-side (unless your cart sizes are gigantic).

Else key the cart data in the db with the session key. You can then (probably) add some kind of hook to your app's session management to flush the db contents when a session is cleared.

Comment: I think keeping cart items in cookies is a horrible idea

Comment: @Mikhail - yeah I don't think that solution is to be recommended

Answer (score 1):

Server side does not actually know when you close the browser. You can ping the server `onBeforeClose` and tell it to flush the cart, but that would mean that when a user closes a tab - it would flush too.

If your user is logged in - you can keep the session cookies for "browser session" only and that way the user would be logged out when he or she comes back. At this point - whenever a user logs in - flush the cart.