# can't navigate with onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am a junior PHP and MySQL programmer and also with low reputation on stack overflow. I searched on google about a question -delete from database after browser close- and found the answer [delete from database after browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111881/delete-from-database-after-browser-close). This solution works ok when I close the browser, but with no browser close when I navigate to other files on my PHP and MySQL project the upper code logs me out the same as I close the browser. Does someone know how to achieve navigation with the solution that a attached (to execute the upper code only when I close the browser)?

Before writing this question, I decided to ask on the solution that I attached by commenting but I couldn't because of the low reputation.

```
<script language="javascript">
function fnUnloadHandler() {
xmlhttp=null; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
 {// code for Firefox, Opera, IE7, etc. 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 } 
 else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
 {// code for IE6, IE5 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
 } 

 if (xmlhttp!=null) 
 {  
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://yourhost/del_cart_actionFile.php",true); 
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
 } 
 else 
 { 
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP."); 
 }
}
</script>
<body onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()">
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example you actually tried and not just a link to a duplicate question?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP or MySQL since the issue seems to be how to call your PHP code, not how to get it working.

Comment: Problem with copying very old code — `else if (window.ActiveXObject)` will _never_ be true any more. You don't have to support IE5 & IE6. Pretty much everything about that "updated" copied answer is outmoded & obsolete.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis at `onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()"`. It should be enough providing the function name.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but the solution was different. Finaly i solved the problem - <body onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()"> had to be <body onunload="fnUnloadHandler()">

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
<body onbeforeunload="fnUnloadHandler()">
```

to

```
<body onBeforeClose="fnUnloadHandler()">
```